# Do some machine learning models in python sklearn accept only single feature in y?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have ran some data with SVR in sklearn

```
from sklearn.svm import SVR
clf = SVR()
clf = clf.fit(train_X, train_y)
y_score3 = clf.predict(test_X)
predict3 = roc_auc_score(test_y, y_score3)
print ("SVR : %(first)s" % {'first':predict3} )
```

However, the console retuns:

```
ValueError: bad input shape (4576, 5)
```

where `train_X` and `train_y` failed to get the `clf.fit()`

my shape of data looks like

```
print (train_X.shape)
(4576, 8)

print (train_y.shape)
(4576, 5)
```

it seems like the model takes the 5 instead of 4576 from train_y in this case

I read the [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVR.html)and it writes:

```
y : array-like, shape (n_samples,)
Target values (class labels in classification, real numbers in regression)
```

does this mean that the model SVR only accept y with one column?
ps- actually my y value is originally one column with discrete 5 classes. I only made them to be dummy with 5 columns.

This happens a lot when I am applying this dataset to different models.
It would be so much appreciated if anyone could kindly answer my question.

Comment: Hmh, the documentation is quite clear: if you want to do a classification, you give a vector of size n=4576 of class labels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the SVR only accepts y with one column, you should reshape your y:

```
train_y.shape=(train_y.shape[0]*train_y.shape[1],1)
```